# Rust, 2 crates with overlapping private functions

Tags: rust, private, encapsulation, organization, code-organization

I'm writing 2 data structures (containers) in rust that have different APIs, but about 50% of the behind the scenes functionality is similar.  FWIW, the first is a redblack tree that stores comparable (`std::cmp::Ord`) data and the other is container with a list like API, does not require the data to be comparable, and uses a buffer sorted similarly to a red black tree.

I think usually both container data structures would be stored as libraries in 2 different crates.  But they share some private functionality like tree rebalancing.  I insist on not maintaining 2 versions of the same private (fairly complex) code, so I think my only option remaining is to combine the 2 data structures into the same crate.  Is there any better option?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better option?

Yes. Make a 3rd crate with the plumbing, and make your 2 porcelain crates depend on it. They don't need to expose publicly the plumbing, keeping encapsulation.

This is rather common. For example, the `regex` (porcelain) crate depends on `regex-syntax` (plumbing) crate, but doesn't expose anything from this crate. As far as the user of `regex` is concerned, `regex-syntax` does not exist. They go as far as [wrapping even the simplest functions](https://docs.rs/regex/1.2.1/src/regex/re_unicode.rs.html#21-23).

Comment: Is there a naming convention for this approach?  Seems like a lot of overhead for the simple task of "friending" (maybe more like spying on) a class.

Comment: I don't think there is a naming convention for this kind of crate. But having a cargo workspace with 3 crates is barely any overhead. And since you mention "friending", I guess you are coming from C++, but if you want to provide 2 data structures as 2 separate libraries in C++, you would also end-up hiding the common plumbing in a 3rd library.